# Avoid displaying 3 time a struct

Tags: scheme, racket, generic-interface

I have define a struct as below,

```
(struct vector (x y z)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc vector port mode)
     (let ([print (if mode write display)])
       (write-string "<")
       (print (vector-x vector))
       (write-string ", ")
       (print (vector-y vector))
       (write-string ", ")
       (print (vector-z vector))
       (write-string ">")))])
```

But I am getting a weird behavior in the REPL where the struct is being display 3 time:

```
> (define a (vector 1 2 3))
> a
<1, 2, 3><1, 2, 3><1, 2, 3>
```

I must be doing something wrong but can not found my issue. Can someone explin me why I have 3 time the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct the output to the output port and everything works:

```
#lang racket
(struct vector (x y z)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc vector port mode)
     (let ([print (if mode write display)])
       (write-string "<" port)
       (print (vector-x vector) port)
       (write-string ", " port)
       (print (vector-y vector) port)
       (write-string ", " port)
       (print (vector-z vector) port)
       (write-string ">" port)))])
```

Comment: Thanks I was not paying attention to the doc :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `port` supplied to `write-proc`:

```
(struct vector (x y z)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc vector port mode)
     (let ([print (if mode write display)])
       (write-string "<" port)
       (print (vector-x vector) port)
       (write-string ", " port)
       (print (vector-y vector) port)
       (write-string ", " port)
       (print (vector-z vector) port)
       (write-string ">" port)))])
```

A less-tedious way to do that would be to change `current-output-port`:

```
(struct vector (x y z)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc vector port mode)
     (let ([print (if mode write display)])
       (parameterize ([current-output-port port]) ;; <== new
         (write-string "<")
         (print (vector-x vector))
         (write-string ", ")
         (print (vector-y vector))
         (write-string ", ")
         (print (vector-z vector))
         (write-string ">"))))])
```

Comment: Oops, I see @soegaard had posted an answer while I was typing mine. I'll keep this around for the `parameterize` tip, I guess.